# Passing a String List in a SOAP request in Flutter

Tags: web-services, flutter, soap, dart

I am making a SOAP Request and this is how my request should be sent:

```
  <id></id>
  <fieldList>
    <string>string</string>
    <string>string</string>
  </fieldList>
```

This is how I have built my envelope:

```
final int id = 21;
List<String> fieldList = new List<String>();

  fieldList = [
    "pinNumber:PIN0000074",
    "dispatchArrivedTime:13.05",
    "towedStatus:C"
  ];

var envelope = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>"
    "<soap:Envelope "
    "xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" "
    "xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" "
    "xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">"
    "<soap:Body>"
    "<update xmlns=\"http://example.com/\">"
    "<id>${id}</id>"
    "<fieldList>${fieldList}</fieldList>"
    "</update>"
    "</soap:Body>"
    "</soap:Envelope>";

    final response = await http.post(
    'http://example.com/vc/ws/towedvehicletable.asmx',
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "text/xml; charset=utf-8",
      "SOAPAction": "http://example.com/update",
      "Host": "example.com"
      //"Accept": "text/xml"
    },
    body: envelope);
```

However, this approach does not work. It would be really helpful if somebody could show me how to pass a String List into my request. I am using Flutter and Dart. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just map list of strings and then join it:

```dart
  List<String> fieldList = ['test1', 'test2'];
  final xmlValues = fieldList.map((v) => '<string>$v</string>').join();
  print(xmlValues);
```

prints:

`<string>test1</string><string>test2</string>`

There's also a [package](https://pub.dev/packages/xml) for working with XML. It allows you to both parse and construct XML documents.